# Inconsistent Rendering between Local and Production Environments in Next.js with Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, subdomain

Some components on my site render differently depending on the environment I'm in. Production doesn't display the same thing as what I see locally.

Here's a concrete example: in the local environment, classes from the "layout" are referenced, whereas in production, some classes seem to be overridden. Additionally, the actual rendering of colors is not consistent between the two.

[image: classes overrided in production]

Additionally, if I force a page refresh on the production site, everything goes back to normal. This makes me think of a caching issue but... which cache? Tailwind doesn't have one. Also, new builds don't fix the problem.

And this is the case for everyone, not just on my personal machine.

I really don't understand what's happening or what I could do to fix this issue.

It's also worth noting that I have 2 Next.js (13) sites on the same URL, so I use a subdomain system to manage the projects.

Here's the configuration for the problematic project, which is quite standard:

```js
module.exports = {
  important: "#app-marketplace",
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./lib/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
  ],
  ....
}
```

I feel like this project might also be fetching some styles from the other project on the same subdomain. However, both projects have their own tailwind.config.js, so I don't see how that would be possible.

```
Projet1
 ...
 tailwind.config.js

Projet2 (problem here)
 ...
 tailwind.config.js
```

In summary, I'm facing inconsistent rendering behaviors between my local and production environments, especially with Tailwind in a Next.js context. Despite thorough checks and understanding of my setup, the root cause remains elusive. I would greatly appreciate any insights or experiences that could guide me towards a resolution.